# How to select random values from an array of dropdowns in Laravel Dusk?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I am new to Laravel Dusk, and currently working on a simple project where you can add multiple dropdowns. The dropdowns have a name like `name = "item[]"`. How can I select each dropdown and select random options?

I have tried :

```
$items = $browser->elements('input[name^="item[]"');

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $item->select(); // Select random options
}
```

but it doesn't work. There's no error, test and assertions are OK but it's not selecting values from the dropdowns.

**Edit**

Just tried :

```
$items = $browser->elements('select[name^="item[]"'); // Change input to select

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $item->select(); // Select random options
}
```

it now gives me an error "call to undefined method `select()`".

Comment: Are the dropdowns `<input>` or `<select>` elements?

Comment: <select> elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;

$items = $browser->elements('select[name^="item[]"]');

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $options = $item->findElements(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('option:not([disabled])'));

    $options[array_rand($options)]->click();
}
```

Comment: it says "WebDriverBy not found".

Comment: You have to import the class: `use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;`

Comment: Wow, it works. Thank you very much. Can you suggest any resources for me to study Laravel Dusk, except laravel.com. So I can research on my own what is "WebDriverBy::cssSelector" and others.

Comment: You can always learn a lot by looking at the code. Dusk internally uses https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver, this is where `WebDriverBy` is from.

Answer (score 0):

use this method to solve your error

> $browser->select('select-box-name');

Comment: It only selects the first dropdown.